# PHP: Create variable based on hashtag

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm using [this tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/) to create an ajax site and am struggling with the PHP. This is the provided code:

**PHP**

```
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
```

I would like to use a naming structure other than `page_1.html`, `page_2.html` etc. My HTML looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Right now the only link that's working is 'Page 4'. How would I rewrite the PHP so that the first three links would work?

**Javascript**

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: We can't fully answer this without also seeing the ajax code which posts the form.  However, the others don't work because they don't follow the pattern `page_number`

Comment: It should also be pointed out that this is currently a security risk

Comment: @Michael Can the code be rewritten so those pages work? That's basically what I'm asking.

Comment: @m.edmondson it isn't actually - he's int typecasting, there's nothing that can be done to break out of it.

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: @colindunnn Yes it can, I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `page4` works, because it is expecting the scripts to be named like `page_number.html`.  Your `home, about, services` do not match that pattern.  To make them work as well, you would need to change the `file_get_contents()` call to allow `page/anything.html`.

The first thing to modify is the function which posts:

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    // Instead of stripping off #page, only 
    // strip off the # to use the rest of the URL
    url=url.replace('#','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Now, this introduces a security risk in PHP.  You need to validate that the value of `$_POST['page']` is strictly alphanumeric so that no one can inject a filename like `../../../../somefile` to read your filesystem.  Using the expression below will allow you to name your files with any alphabetic and numeric characters, but will reject dots and null bytes, which are the primary dangers in a [file path-injection / directory traversal attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Relative_Path_Traversal).

```
if(empty($_POST['page'])) die("0");
// Remove the typecast so you can use the whole string
//$page = (int)$_POST['page'];
// Just use the post val.  This is safe because we'll validate it with preg_match() before use...
$page = $_POST['page'];

// And validate it as alphanumeric before reading the filesystem
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i', $_POST['page']) && file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.html')) {
  // Remove the page_ to use the whole thing
  echo file_get_contents('pages/'.$page.'.html');
}
else echo 'There is no such page!';
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried cutting and pasting and am getting a "No such page" error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your getting the error because $page is undefined.  Use the code I posted, or add $page = $_POST['page']; about the if statement to get his code to work

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to alter more than just this to get it working.

1. Change the JS so that it doesn't remove anything from the URL except the pound sign:

   ```
   url=url.replace('#page','');
   ```

   Needs to be:

   ```
   url=url.replace('#','');
   ```
2. Change the PHP to handle strings:

   ```
   if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

   // Only allow alphanumeric characters and an underscore in page names
   $page = preg_replace( "/[^\w]/", '', $_POST['page']);

   if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.html'))
       echo file_get_contents('pages/'.$page.'.html');
   else echo 'There is no such page!';
   ```
3. Now create the pages in the `pages/` directory.

   - `<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>` would be `home.html`
   - `<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>` would be `about.html`
   - `<li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>` would be `services.html`
   - `<li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>` would be `page4.html`

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP to this:

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/'.$page.'.html');
```

Now you are using the whole hash tag so #about will lead to:
pages/about.html

Change this in thee javascript function loadPage

```
url=url.replace('#page','');
```

becomes

```
url=url.replace('#','');
```

Comment: oh crap sorry.  instead of removing url.replace, check out the edit