# partial page update with navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First of all, I apologize because this is my first time trying to code a website (or anything), so this might be a stupid question.
I have a web page where I would like to update only a single div when a link in the navigation bar is clicked.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="header">
        </header>
        <section id="section1">
            <div>
            </div>
            <nav id="mainnav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="1.html"><b>1</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="2.html"><b>2</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="3.html"><b>3</b></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
        <section id="section2">
            <div id="mainwrap">
                <div id="main">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I know, it's a lot of useless stuff, but you get the point. What I'm trying to do is as you click on 1, 2, 3, etc., only the content of the div "mainwrap" changes, as does the URL (so the page does not refresh, but the URL changes from www.website/1.html to website/2.html, etc. and the content of the one div changes). I have different HTML files for 1, 2, and 3, each with different "main" divs, which ideally will be inserted into the "mainwrap."

I've tried following along with tutorials like https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/ and other stackoverflow posts like [how to do partial page update with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002580/how-to-do-partial-page-update-with-jquery). That second one seems like what I want to do, but when I try to implement it, it still doesn't work. Is there a simple fix that I am just missing because I don't know much about coding? (Also, I'm using Dreamweaver. I don't know if that makes a difference.)

Thanks!

Comment: If the url changes the page will reload.

Comment: Hi everyone, I just wanted to thank you all for helping me to figure this out. I realized that what I needed to do required a little bit more than just html and javascript, and I eventually found this page, which is exactly what I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791106/php-create-variable-based-on-hashtag. I hope everyone who is trying to do what I am has as much success finding the right information! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are right [how to do partial page update with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002580/how-to-do-partial-page-update-with-jquery) is exactly what you need. I assume you are new to jquery stuff so here is the complete markup http://jsfiddle.net/yrbvnayy/ that will get your job done!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="edit-Type" edit="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

        </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
<header id="header">
</header>
<section id="section1">
  <div>
  </div>
  <nav id="mainnav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="1.html"><b>1</b></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="2.html"><b>2</b></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="3.html"><b>3</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
<section id="section2">
  <div id="mainwrap">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#mainnav li a").click(function(e) {
    // prevent from going to the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the href
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#main").load(href, function() {
        // do something after content has been loaded
    });
});
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code isn't loading any of the other pages. The home page comes up, but when I click on a link, the page just sits there and doesn't do anything:/

Comment: Well there are no 1.html or 2.html or 3.html. It's just a sample code to get it loaded! You need to have this page running from a http server with necessary html files you need displayed!

Comment: All of the other html files are on dreamweaver, and they load when i do not have a javascript file attached. Does dreamweaver usually have a problem with javascript files?

Comment: Where are those dreamweaver files located? Read more about Same Origin policy @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: They do have the same origin. They are all saved on my computer in the site root folder, and I'm just using the "preview in browser" button. It's not like some of the files are already on the server and some of them are stored elsewhere.

Comment: Well if all the files are in the site's root folder. It should run without any issues! I'm not sure what is Preview in Browser'. Is the site running? Does it show any errors in browser console?

Comment: The "preview in browser" button just lets you see what it looks like in a web browser (google chrome, for example). The console gives a warning that the webkitURL is depreciated, but no errors.

Comment: Does this html file along with 1.html, 2.html,3.html exist in same folder? Can you run the site instead of Preview and see if that works? If so what's the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same reference for jquery ajax to explain the answer. [How to do partial page update with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002580/how-to-do-partial-page-update-with-jquery)

In your case I will apply the above usage as

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mainnav a').click(function(e){
 //either use e.preventDefault() to stop the default event or return false
   var loc=$(this).attr('href');
   $('#mainwrap').load(loc);
   //This should load the html content to your div
})
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

An alternative if you just want the div of the HTML pages you are pointing.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mainnav a').click(function(e){
  // either use e.preventDefault() to stop the default event or return false
  e.preventDefault();
  var loc = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    url: loc,
    type: 'GET', // can be GET or POST depending on your requirement
    success: function(data, textstatus, xhr)
    {
      var div = $(data).find('#main');
      $('#mainwrap').html(div);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error)
    {
      alert('Error - ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
  // This should load the html content to your div
})
});
</script>
```

> Fore more ajax related documentation you can go through http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this still reloads the entire page. Do you think it might be fixed if it was actually on the server instead of dreamweaver? Or does it matter?

Comment: I have added an edit, if your ajax call fails, it will throw an error and tell you what was the issue. May be this is what you are looking for<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281769/load-works-in-ie-and-dreamweaver-preview-but-no-opera-and-chrome>

Comment: Haha, the error just says "undefined." I thought that link would have helped, so instead of previewing in google chrome, I tried another browser, but it still didn't work. So I uploaded the couple files I had to the server and tried it on there, and again, it didn't work. So I don't think the problem is with the source of the files.

Answer (score -1):

The example you cite is using php, which can do what you want.

Comment: So if i just change my files to 1.php instead of 1.html, it'll work?

Comment: no look at the example a bit closer, the php process of loading differing content has an example you can download. I recommend you download it and see how it works